# Not able to loop through array in JSON, jQuery

Tags: jquery, json, serialization, loops

I've a form with input fields as follows:

```
<form "data-qustion_form"=true>
  <input name="question[description]" value="quesd">
  <input name="question[answers][0][description]" value="ansd1">
  <input name="question[answers][1][description]" value="ansd2">
</form>
```

I'm using https://github.com/marioizquierdo/jquery.serializeJSON to convert the form data to json. Also tried using https://stackoverflow.com/a/8407771/707636. Both works great. But the I'm not able to loop through the array in the json.

I've following js

```
$("[data-question_form]").on("submit", function(e) {
  var o = $(this).serializeObject();  // $(this).serializeJSON(); both results same
  console.log(o);
  console.log(o["question"]);
  console.log(o["question"]["answers"]);
  $.each(question["answers"], function() {
    console.log("print test");  // I don't see this on console in Chrome inspector
  }
  e.preventDefault();
}
```

The output on console in Chrome inspector is as follow:

```
Object {utf8: "✓", question: Object}
Object {description: "quesd", answers: Array[0]}
[1362289041238: Object, 1362289045644: Object]
```

Further expanding `[1362289041238: Object, 1362289045644: Object]` shows the `length: 0`.

How can I iterate through this array to read each answer description in jQuery?

Comment: `$.each(question["answers"], function() {` looks wrong to me.

Comment: I did also try `$.each(question["answers"], function(k,v) { console.log(v); }`, didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I just solved it but making a small change in the `name` attribute of input elements. Added  `[]` before the counter as follows:

```
<input name="question[answers][][0][description]" value="ansd1">
<input name="question[answers][][1][description]" value="ansd2">
```

Now I'm able to loop through it :)

Answer (score 1):

I wasn't able to find any problem with your code (see [example](http://jsfiddle.net/mgibsonbr/V7b8M/)), either using `serializeObject` - with the code in the linked answer - or using `serializeJSON` - with the code from GitHub. Your markup, however, had to be adjusted:

```
<form "data-qustion_form"=true>
```

to:

```
<form data-question_form="true">
```

P.S. as @jchapa pointed out, the `question["answers"]` was wrong too - and the parenthesis didn't balance. But I'm assuming it's just the code you pasted here, your actual code must be right (or you wouldn't get any results at all).

```
  $.each(o["question"]["answers"], function() {
    console.log("print test");  // I don't see this on console in Chrome inspector
  });
});
```

Comment: Nice answer - pushed you to 10k ;)